# Использование API Яндекс метрики в C#

Tags: c#

Добрый день, нужно написать программу на C# которая получает при помощи Яндекс метрики число посещений разных сайтов. 
Вопрос: реализуемо ли это на C# при помощи https запросов? И нужны ли сторонний библиотеки для этого?

Comment: `C#` позволяет формировать какие угодно http/https запросы при помощи класса `System.Net.Http.HttpClient`.

Comment: Окей, а что насчет доболнителных библиотек? Я слышал про xNet и JSON.net обязательные ли они или нет? Извиняюсь если глупый вопрос, первый раз работаю с сетевыми запросами.

Comment: @Maccord, ответ от любого API, как правило, приходит в формате JSON. JSON.NET-это удобная библиотека, которая позволяет выполнить десериализацию ответной строки в объект.

Comment: @Maccord , не обязательные, но для удобства было бы неплохо их использовать. Если Вам нужно отправить буквально пару однотипных запросов и распарсить несложный json, то, в принципе, можете обойтись и без них.

Comment: Еще посоветую библиотечку RestSharp в качестве более удобной замены HttpClient'а. Удобнее собирать параметризованный запрос, более четкое и короткое время жизни объекта клиента, понятные объекты запроса и ответа.